# converting php variables to javascript.Not working

Tags: php, javascript

```
<?php
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
?>
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<?php 

   $variable=10;
?>
<script>

   var myVar = "<?php echo $variable; ?>";
   alert(myVar);

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

this is my source code and it is not working. My concern is converting the php variable as javascript variable..The alert displays the entire line as a string
   
instead of printing the value...Have tried json function as well.No use.what should I be doing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should definitely not tell the browser that it's receiving JavaScript when it is in fact receiving HTML:

```
header("Content-type: text/html");
```

The fact that the HTML contains a `<script>` tag, which itself contains JavaScript is something entirely different.

Additionally, a *much* better way on injecting PHP variables in JavaScript is

```
var myVar = <?php echo json_encode($variable); ?>;
```

Note no quotes around the value -- `json_encode` quotes automatically as required. There are certain fine points about injecting variables that make both this one and your original approach not bulletproof, but `json_encode` is much better as a default choice.

Comment: in HTML5 the type attribute isn't necessary. js is assumed

Comment: @Bart: Neither are the double quotes the original had. What is your point? That it's better to judge on a case-by-case basis rather than be safe (well, *much safer* if not 100% safe) across the board?

Comment: @Jon my point is that the OP stated he tried json_decode already, and it's not relevant to this problem.

Comment: @Bart: That's why it's in the second half of the answer: it's not the main point. But it is IMHO important enough that it should be mentioned. Plain `echo` is just an invitation to break.

Answer (score 6):

Remove this line:

```
header("Content-type: application/javascript");
```

This tells browser to output this page as text (i.e browser will not render it), JavaScript should be loaded into HTML files.

Comment: or at least change it to `text/html` instead.

Answer (score 0):

I guess your file has the .php extension. In this case, a simple `<script>var myVar=<?php print $variable; ?></script>` will do, no need to encase it in quotes or double quotes :P